# Index of the item curent being show in a <select> box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box with the following data

```
<select>
    <option>Bill</option>
    <option>Ted</option>
    <option>Bogus</option>
</select>
```

When i select "Bogus" i want to return 2 back to a function, because this is the third item.

Any idea how to do this with jQuery? Something like

```
jQuery("#colour").change(function(){
    alert( $(this).index );         
});
```

doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all this jquery business, we forget how it was done before... ;-)

It's

```
this.selectedIndex
```

Comment: plain JavaScript. Very nice! ;-)

Comment: I know. Sometimes I'm amazed by all that splendid functionality that jquery hides ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify your jquery to use the index method

`$('option:selected', this).index()`

http://jsfiddle.net/rcFGj/